# DynamoDB createIfNotExist

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In dynamoDB I should create some kind of log information, that has a state that user could change. But it is unnecessary extra information. Main question is:

1. I have an object:

```
{
  id: '123',
  log: 'mybestlog',
  state: 'PENDING'
}
```

2. I want to create this document object if document with same `id` not exists.
3. I want to get back current object and flag, if object with same `id` exits.

Hope I tell all enough clear.

I tried to do:

```js
      const result: PutItemOutput = await this.dynamodbClient.put({
          TableName: this.config.tableName,
          Item: {
            ...newItem,
            status: statusEnum.PENDING,
            creationDate: moment().toISOString(),
          },
          ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(id)',
          ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW',
      })
        .promise()
        .catch((error) => {
          this.logger.error(`### END-ERROR ${methodDescription} | error: ${error}`, metadata);
          throw new InternalServerErrorException(error.stack);
        });
```

But can't found any `Items` or flags `Exist` in response. I got `AWS.DynamoDB.PutItemOutput`:

```
      {
        Attributes?,
        ConsumedCapacity?,
        ItemCollectionMetrics?,
      }
```

Please help me, what the best solution is in my situation.

Comment: Does the Item get created?

Comment: @SethGeoghegan what item should get created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't get a response with a flag that an item exits in dynamoDB, the way you're thinking.

When you call put operation with that **ConditionExpression**. The two major outcomes and those that matter for you are:

1. Your **ConditionExpression** succeeded and you'll get **ALL_NEW** values in **Attributes** Key.
2. Otherwise you'll get some error. The one that  matters for you is **ConditionalCheckFailedException** which means that **ConditionExpression** failed and the key already exists.

You'll need to tailor a response yourself accordingly.